# Matching row data from excel to an array in php

Tags: php

`$emapData[3]` is row 4  input data in the excel, how would I match  `$emapData[3]` to `$categories` which is an array. Like if `$emapData[3](row 4 excel input , so if user puts AMT 1)` is == AMT 1 which exist in `$categories` array it will insert 5801D447D5583 to the Database which is the value of  AMT 1. Also whatever input from the user it will match to categories array it exists. I have tried below.

```
 $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
        if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0)
        {
            $file = fopen($filename, "r");
            $count = 0;
            $stud_id = strtoupper(uniqid());
            $categories=array("5801D447D5583" => "AMT 1","5801D447D5583" => "AMT 2","5801D457CAF7F" => "AMT 3");
            while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
            {
                $count++;
                $stud_id = strtoupper(uniqid());
                $added_by = $_SESSION['userid'];
                if($count > 1) {
                echo $count;
                $sql = "INSERT into students(stud_id ,stud_no , first_name , last_name, date_added ,added_by) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]', '$emapData[2]' ,NOW(), '$added_by')";

                $emapData[3] = $categories['AMT 1'];
                $sql1 = "INSERT into categories(student_id ,category_id ) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[3]')";



                mysql_query($sql);

            }
```

Comment: try `array_search()`  http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use array search

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

> array_search — Searches the array for a given value and returns the first corresponding key if successful

So something like

```
$value = array_search('AMT 1', $categories);
```

Outputs:

```
5801D447D5583
```

So as you said all this

> $emapData[3] is row 4 input data in the excel , how would I match $emapData[3] to $categories which is an array. Like if $emapData[3](row 4 excel input , so if user puts AMT 1) is == AMT 1

you would put something like `array_search($emapData[3], $categories);`

But I would check if it's found by doing

```
if( $value !== false)
```

Note- you need to use `!==` that checks the type as array search can return index `0` in some cases which is false in PHP.  IN your particular case you don't have index `0` but it's good practice anyway.  If you read the PHP documentation, specifically this warning.

> **Warning** This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

That is what it is saying.

Cheers.

**UPDATE**

This line in your code

```
 $emapData[3] = $categories['AMT 1'];
```

I would replace with at least

```
 $emapData[3] = array_search($emapData[3], $categories);
 if(false !== $emapData[3]){
    //insert
 }else{
    //do something else?
 }
```

However there is a lot of other "Stuff" such as using `mysql_` family of functions which are removed in PHP7, as well as directly inserting data into your query, which is a security issue, even from a file.  It's called SQL Injection.

Personally I wouldn't overwrite `$emapData[3]` and instead use a separate variable, but I think that is the least of your worries at this point.

But those things are beyond the scope of this question, however I do strongly suggest using something like PDO and prepared statements instead.

**UPDATE1**

This bit of code
     while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
     {
     ///..other code
      if($count > 1) { //missing closing }
            echo $count;
            $sql = "INSERT into students(stud_id ,stud_no , first_name , last_name, date_added ,added_by) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]', '$emapData[2]' ,NOW(), '$added_by')";

```
        $emapData[3] = $categories['AMT 1'];
        $sql1 = "INSERT into categories(student_id ,category_id ) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[3]')";

        mysql_query($sql);
  } //end while
```

You'll note besides missing the ending `}` which I pointed out in comments, you never call `mysql_query($sql1);` so this second insert is never executed.

Ok... So the simple fix is to just add that in like this:

```
 while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
 ///..other code
  if($count > 1) { //missing closing }
        echo $count;
        $sql = "INSERT into students(stud_id ,stud_no , first_name , last_name, date_added ,added_by) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]', '$emapData[2]' ,NOW(), '$added_by')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        $emapData[3] = $categories['AMT 1'];
        $sql1 = "INSERT into categories(student_id ,category_id ) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[3]')";
        mysql_query($sql1);
  } //end while
```

You'll notice I moved the first one `mysql_query($sql);` which is simply for readability sake, you create a query and execute it.   So it reads better to create 1 query execute it, then create a second query and execute that, the two things are separate operations independent of one another.

The last bit is I don't know exactly how you dealt with the original issue, but putting that all together should be something like:

```
 while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE)
 {
 ///..other code
  if($count > 1) { 
        echo $count;

        $emapData[3] = array_search($emapData[3], $categories);
       if(false !== $emapData[3]){
              $sql = "INSERT into students(stud_id ,stud_no , first_name , last_name, date_added ,added_by) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[0]','$emapData[1]', '$emapData[2]' ,NOW(), '$added_by')";
              mysql_query($sql);

              $emapData[3] = $categories['AMT 1'];
              $sql1 = "INSERT into categories(student_id ,category_id ) values ('$stud_id','$emapData[3]')";
              mysql_query($sql1);
        }else{
            /*
               do something else?
               It's a question as I have no way to know the importance of
               the array search to the insert, maybe it's ok if it's null.
               maybe that is an error that ruins one or both inserts?
               So without knowing that, I have no idea on the exact
               implementation of non-matching states.
             */
        } 
     }//end if $count
  } //end while
```

Comment: can you show me a sample bro how would i integrate array search to the problem i stated above?

Comment: could you please integrate it from the code above? just wanted to know .

Comment: array_search($emapData[3], $categories); what is the value of emapdata now ? which ill be inserting to the database?

Comment: array_search($emapData[3], $categories); , what if its true ? what would be the value ? is the value og emapData 3 anything that exist in categories?

Comment: if it's true the value is the Key of that item, as I put in my answer and as the PHP documentation says.  eg. `returns the first corresponding key if successful`  Which again, if the value you are searching is `AMT 1` it will be `5801D447D5583` as I "again" put in my answer.

Comment: so that would be  $emapData[3] = array_search($emapData[3], $categories); if ($emapData[3] !== false) {} sql1  = inser into test1 , value = $emapData[3] ?

Comment: something like that, but I wouldn't overwrite your data, I would make a new variable for it, as I "again" said in my answer.

Comment: `E=mc^2`  no idea.

Comment: well considering you never execute this query `$sql1` I'm not really surprised.  You only ever call `mysql_query($sql);`

Comment: is the example above you have give the correct one?

Comment: I don't know what that means, I took the code from your question and pointed out an issue I see, rather that is "the correct example" or not I have no way to know, but based on the information I have everything I said is true.

Comment: can you please Show me the integrated one , i mean the point  you are trying to prove Sir ?

Comment: It's fine often, posters assume that an answer has some intimate knowledge of what they are doing, but in fact I only know what I was given in the question.

Comment: I understand Sir

Comment: Also I don't have whatever code you put in place of the original code, so the whole issue with `array_search` needs to be added as I don't know the exact solution to that based on your question alone.

Comment: dont worry bro i have the missing one , i just did not included it in the sample above

Comment: That's fine, as I said, people think that an exact solution to their problem can be given, and that is not the case. I can tell you how to do it, but it's up to you how you implement that.

Comment: I would strongly recommend using PDO, prepared statements, and in this case, "transactions", but that is way outside the scope of this question.  Something for you to google though.  Transactions would let you fail both queries if only one succeeds, as it is now the first could insert ant he second fail leaving an unstable state, maybe..  see http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php

Comment: are you still there Sir ?